# How to logout a specific user programatically?

Tags: users

I need to logout a specific user programmatically whose uid is known to me.

I think I need to destroy the session. Is there any table in drupal store that value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [drupal_session_destroy_uid](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_destroy_uid/7) function.

> Ends a specific user's session(s).

Example:

```
drupal_session_destroy_uid($uid_to_logout);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used

`\Drupal::service('session_manager')->delete($uid);`

for D8

Answer (score 0):

You can condition in this code to logout user

```
// Programmatically logs out the current user
global $user;
$tmp = NULL;
session_destroy();
user_module_invoke('logout', $tmp, $user);
$user = drupal_anonymous_user(); //or any user you get from database
```